# Linux file extensions while uploading file from windows to linux box

Tags: linux, spring-integration

Is there anyway we can detect if file writing is complete before start processing file? What i mean is, we have java program written in spring integration and it polls .zip file, as soon as it sees that file, it picks up and start processing it. But in case of large .zip files, before it writes complete file,it is picking up that file and causing an issue.

Does anyone know how to detect if file write is still in progress?

Comment: Nope, no way to tell if complete or a slow remote delay. Typical technique, alluded to in your posting title, is to write to, say, `file.working` and change to `file.zip` when done.